# innerHTML to return a filtered syntax name of all the class with one name

Tags: javascript, class, filter, innerhtml

im using this code to return the attrb name of the class tooltip (have more than one class in all the page)

CODE:

```
var hrefs = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip_sticky');
for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; ++i) {
    var item = hrefs[i].innerHTML;      
}
alert(item);
```

HTML:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/klS0N.png)

[image]

but it only return the `<span....` of the last tooltip_sticky class, but i dont want this, i want to get the hrefs that have MISSION=1, i know its a matter of filter, but i cant first get the list of hrefs(i used another code that was getting the href outside the name="..", but the href inside, no...

**im planning to get automatically all the hrefs that have mission=1 in the page, and open each one in another window automatically, its for a chrome extension!!**

if someone can help me please, while this i will read about innerHTML getattribute

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly it is you're trying to do with the text of the links? It's not at all clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an alert() outside the loop so of course you only get the last one.  In a statically scoped programming language, something like this wouldn't even compile because item is introduced inside the loop and used outside it.

Comment: i fixed it by setting the alert inside the loop, but it never show the  text of name:"...."

Comment: What you are doing is passing the alert raw html without the <html>...</html> tags.  Alerts don't understand html markup.  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: get the **?page=fleet&amp;galaxy=8&amp;system=80&amp;planet=3&amp;planettype=1&amp;target_mission=1** (have another, but i want all the href that have  mission=1 in the end) and open it in another window

Comment: You don't do that with an alert.  You need a webView.  I'm afraid you have too far to go for me to continue on this thread.  Do the reading.

Comment: i got the name, but only the firt one using this -> `var namex = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip_sticky")[0].getAttribute("name",2);
alert(namex);`  but only show one name, and i dont know how to filter it for the only mission=1